# uint32_t seems to be unknown in the CMSIS Math files?

Tags: arm, stm32, stdint, cmsis

I am getting the error:

> CMSIS/DSP/Include/arm_math.h:3943:3: error: unknown type name 'uint32_t'; did you mean 'wint_t'?

I could add stdint.h to the arm_math.h but I assume I did something wrong in the first place.
Surely the CMSIS developer would have added an include if neccessary?
Any suggestions what to do? I used arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stdint.h` is [included](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/core_cm7.h#L44) in the header file for the relevant core, which - in turn - will be included [as long as you define one of](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS/blob/master/CMSIS/Include/arm_math.h#L301) `ARM_MATH_CM4`, `ARM_MATH_CM7`, etc..

> I could add stdint.h to the arm_math.h but I assume I did something wrong in the first place.

Yes: I think you just need to ensure that one of the afore-mentioned macros is defined.

From the [CMSIS-DSP documentation](https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/index.html):

> Define the appropriate pre processor MACRO ARM_MATH_CM7 or ARM_MATH_CM4 or ARM_MATH_CM3 or ARM_MATH_CM0 or ARM_MATH_CM0PLUS depending on the target processor in the application.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding this ARM_MATH_CM4 ( STM32F4 ) to the symbols tab in the Symbols Tab under

C/C++ General
Paths and Symbols

worked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbdLH.png)

Before that it throwed 660 errors when I accidentially added ARM_MATH_CM4 to the other paths in the Includes tab.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).